# Airflow secure-file-priv option - cannot insert data from file to database

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG of three tasks. The first one checks if csv file exists, the second creates MySQL table and the third one inserts the data from csv file into MySQL table. First two tasks succeed but the last one not saying that due to secure-file-priv option I have no rigts to insert data from file to database.

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=5)
}

with DAG('sql_operator_from_csv_to_mysql',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval='@daily', template_searchpath=['/opt/airflow/sql_files_mysql'], catchup=True) as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(task_id='check_file_exists', bash_command='ls /opt/airflow/store_files/students_data.csv | sha1sum', retries=2, retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=15))
    t2 = MySqlOperator(task_id='create_mysql_table', mysql_conn_id="mysql_conn", sql="create_table.sql")
    t3 = MySqlOperator(task_id='insert_into_table', mysql_conn_id="mysql_conn", sql="insert_into_table.sql")
```

SQL statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/store_files/students_data.csv' INTO TABLE students_db FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

mysql.cnf file is as following.

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv= ""
```

I have tried to mark 'secure-file-priv' option as an empty string and showing the location of a csv file but none of them are working.

```
secure-file-priv= ""
secure-file-priv= "/opt/airflow/store_files"
```

Error message saying:

```
[2022-06-12, 09:44:24 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1774} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/mysql/operators/mysql.py", line 84, in execute
    hook.run(self.sql, autocommit=self.autocommit, parameters=self.parameters)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi.py", line 205, in run
    self._run_command(cur, sql_statement, parameters)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi.py", line 229, in _run_command
    cur.execute(sql_statement)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1290, 'The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement')
[2022-06-12, 09:44:24 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1288} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=sql_operator_from_csv_to_mysql, task_id=insert_into_table, execution_date=20220612T094413, start_date=20220612T094424, end_date=20220612T094424
[2022-06-12, 09:44:24 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:98} ERROR - Failed to execute job 10 for task insert_into_table ((1290, 'The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement'); 1190)
[2022-06-12, 09:44:24 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-06-12, 09:44:24 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: can you share your docker-compose.yaml file ?

Comment: You can download it here:
https://easyupload.io/ju60xp

Comment: can you share the create.sql file and also the csv file which you are using?  I'm trying to simulate it on my local computer with an exact same docker-compose file!

Comment: create.sql file:
https://ucarecdn.com/2987ec7f-1c08-4235-92f0-c5d09e17288a/

csv file:
https://ucarecdn.com/63a8ae7b-13c2-409f-9c99-043fe1468838/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make some minor modifications in the docker-compose.yaml file.

My docker-compose.yaml file is as below

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:2.3.2
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.3.2}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}

  volumes:
  - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
  - ./store_files:/usr/local/airflow/store_files_airflow
  - ./sql_files_mysql:/usr/local/airflow/sql_files
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  mysql:
      image: mysql:latest
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=airflow
      volumes:
        - ./store_files:/var/lib/mysql-files
        - ./mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf
      restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  # You can enable flower by adding "--profile flower" option e.g. docker-compose --profile flower up
  # or by explicitly targeted on the command line e.g. docker-compose up flower.
  # See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/
  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    profiles:
      - flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

And the sql.conf file is as below

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv= ""
```

Comment: Can you please try to use this docker-compose and let me know if you are facing the same issues

Comment: I changed the compose file and started all containers but when executing command 'airflow dags list' then any of the DAGs files that I have created and are in my dags directory doesn't show up in airflow container dags list (can't find them via Web UI also).